# Python - Loop through nested loops print item if it changes

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am looping through several nested loops. I want to print the item of the first loop if it changes. How can I do that?

```
for slope in slopeList:
    for yarddist in yardDistList:
                      for chiptreesperacre in chipAcreList:
                          for chipvolpertree in chipVolList:
                              for smalllognumber in smallAcreList:
                                   for smalltreevolpertree in smallVolList:
                                       for largelogperacre in largeAcreList:
                                           for largetreevolpertree in largeVolList:
                                               data = [slope, yarddist, chiptreesperacre, chipvolpertree, smalllognumber, smalltreevolpertree, largelogperacre, largetreevolpertree]
                                               if slope changes:
                                                   print data
```

Comment: What do you by "it changes"? That it's different from the value in the previous iteration?

Comment: loop in loop in loop in loop in loop in loop in loop in loop serioulsy?

Comment: what else do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value you saw previously, and compare them:

```
previous_slope = None
for slope in as_many_loops_as_you_like:
    data = [slope, other_stuff]
    if slope != previous_slope:
        print data
        previous_slope = slope
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add previous_slope to a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and watch the length of it after addition in the inner loop:

```
slope = set()
slope.add(previous_slope)
old_length = len(slope)
for first_loop:
   slope.add(current_slope)
   if len(slope) > old_length: 
     print 'Changed!'
     break
```

Repeat this pattern for every inner loop.